# Validation a string length : either X or Y, not between X and Y?

Tags: c#, validation

I often use the validation framework with something like :

```
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength=5)]
public string MyString{ get; set; }
```

This allows me specify the MyString length must be between 5 and 10 characters long.

Now I have to check if the string is either 5 long, or 10 long. No other length are allowed.
I'm quite sure the `StringLength` attribute is inadequate, so how to do that ? Have I to extend the validation framework and how ?

thx

Comment: Can you use a regular expression instead? Then the expression would be `.{5}(.{5})?`

Comment: nice idea... :) my string only digits, so I'll use `^\d{5}(\d{5})?$`.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: answer instead of comment the question. I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can (I'm not familiar with the validation library in question) you can use a regular expression.

The regular expression to validate any character, length 5 or 10, would be:

```
^.{5}(.{5})?$
```

If you only have digits, you can use:

```
^\d{5}(\d{5})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

using the fluent validation api i'd just use:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property).Length(10);
```

Comment: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/   so much better than the rigid and unflexible approach provided by the built in stuff

Comment: allright, but it does not use the System.DataAnnotations.* tools, doesn't it? Your suggestion means I have to change my current validation method. Am I right ?

Comment: yes. if you can - i whole heartedly suggest you do. it's so much more expressive.